# why css is not apply on list using JQM in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-mobile, angularjs-directive

[image]can you please tell me why my list is not display .
I used this https://github.com/angular-widgets/angular-jqm here is the documenetation 
http://angular-widgets.github.io/angular-jqm/master/docs/#/api/jqm.directive:jqmListview

http://plnkr.co/edit/AfUQ5PGjKi12afqgFRfZ?p=preview

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', function(scope){
var friends = [
    {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Erika', age:27, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Patrick', age:40, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Samantha', age:60, gender:'girl'}
];
  scope.items=friends;
}])
```

is there any one idea how to add css ?

any body idea why css is not apply using JQM

Comment: the names are being displayed in the plunkr, which list you trying to refer in the question?

Comment: but their css ? actually when you see document list view have css.please check css of list

Comment: Please ping me when you free

Comment: I am not able to erite anything on chat ..:( I think I have less points..sorry

Comment: the come to this [room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60686/room-for-nidhishkrishnan-and-neetu-sharma)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this

**[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/IwaMiqtQIeZN8HSrooJk?p=preview)**

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Fixed Header!</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
 <ul data-role="listview">
    <li><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li>
    <li><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li>
    <li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Fixed Footer!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please look my this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666242/how-to-make-tab-bar-in-angular-js-with-sliding-effect

Comment: please post the Question